# Handling line feed in ANTLR4 grammar with Python target

Tags: python-3.x, grammar, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree, linefeed

I am working on an **ANTLR4 grammar for parsing Python DSL scripts** (a subset of Python, basically) with the **target set as the Python 3**. I am having difficulties handling the line feed.

In my grammar, I use `lexer::members` and `NEWLINE` embedded code based on [Bart Kiers's Python3 grammar for ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4) which are **ported to Python** so that they can be used with Python 3 runtime for ANTLR instead of Java. My grammar differs from the one provided by Bart (which is almost the same used in the [Python 3 spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)) since in my DSL I need to target only certain elements of Python. Based on extensive testing of my grammar, I do think that the Python part of the grammar in itself is not the source of the problem and so I won't post it here in full for now.

The input for the grammar is a file, catched by the file_input rule:

```
file_input: (NEWLINE | statement)* EOF;
```

The grammar performs rather well on my DSL and produces correct ASTs. The only problem I have is that my lexer rule `NEWLINE` clutters the AST with `\r\n` nodes and proves troublesome when trying to extend the generated `MyGrammarListener` with my own `ExtendedListener` which inherits from it.

Here is my `NEWLINE` lexer rule:

```
NEWLINE
 : ( {self.at_start_of_input()}? SPACES
   | ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' | '\f' ) SPACES?
   )
   {
    import re
    from MyParser import MyParser
    new_line = re.sub(r"[^\r\n\f]+", "", self._interp.getText(self._input)) 
    spaces = re.sub(r"[\r\n\f]+", "", self._interp.getText(self._input)) 
    next = self._input.LA(1)

    if self.opened > 0 or next == '\r' or next == '\n' or next == '\f' or next == '#':
        self.skip()
    else:
        self.emit_token(self.common_token(self.NEWLINE, new_line))

        indent = self.get_indentation_count(spaces)
        if len(self.indents) == 0:
            previous = 0
        else:
            previous = self.indents[-1]

        if indent == previous:
            self.skip()
        elif indent > previous:
            self.indents.append(indent)
            self.emit_token(self.common_token(MyParser.INDENT, spaces))
        else:
            while len(self.indents) > 0 and self.indents[-1] > indent:
                self.emit_token(self.create_dedent())
                del self.indents[-1]
   };
```

The `SPACES` lexer rule fragment that `NEWLINE` uses is here:

```
 fragment SPACES
 : [ \t]+
 ;
```

I feel I should also add that both `SPACES` and `COMMENTS` are ultimately being skipped by the grammar, but only after the `NEWLINE` lexer rule is declared, which, as far as I know, should mean that there are no adverse effects from that, but I wanted to include it just in case.

```
SKIP_
 : ( SPACES | COMMENT ) -> skip
 ;
```

When the input file is run without any empty lines between statements, everything runs as it should. However, if there are empty lines in my file (such as between import statements and variable assignement), I get the following errors:

```
line 15:4 extraneous input '\r\n    ' expecting {<EOF>, 'from', 'import', NEWLINE, NAME}
line 15:0 extraneous input '\r\n' expecting {<EOF>, 'from', 'import', NEWLINE, NAME}
```

As I said before, when line feeds are omitted in my input file, the grammar and my `ExtendedListener` perform as they should, so the problem is definitely with the `\r\n` not being matched by the `NEWLINE` lexer rule - even the error statement I get says that it does not match alternative `NEWLINE`.

The AST produced by my grammar looks like this:
[image: AST generated by ANTLR4 from my grammar and input file.]

I would really appreciate any help with this since I cannot see why my `NEWLINE` lexer rule woud fail to match `\r\n` as it should and I would like to allow empty lines in my DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the problem is definitely with the \r\n not being matched by the
>   NEWLINE lexer rule

There is another explanation. An LL(1) parser would stop at the first mismatch, but ANTLR4 is a very smart LL(*) : it tries to match the input past the mismatch.

As I don't have your `statement` rule and your input around line 15, I'll demonstrate a possible case with the following grammar :

```
grammar Question;

/* Extraneous input parsing NL and spaces. */

@lexer::members {
  public boolean at_start_of_input() {return true;}; // even if it always returns true, it's not the cause of the problem
}

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 2108");}
    :   ( NEWLINE
    |     statement
              {System.out.println("found <<" + $statement.text + ">>");}
        )* EOF
    ;

statement
    :   'line ' NUMBER NEWLINE 'something else' NEWLINE
    ;

NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
NEWLINE
    : ( {at_start_of_input()}? SPACES
       | ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' | '\f' ) SPACES?
      )
   ;

SKIP_
    :   SPACES -> skip
    ;

fragment SPACES
    :   [ \t]+
    ;
```

Input file t.text :

```
line 1
   something else
```

Execution :

```
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar"
$ alias
alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ hexdump -C t.text 
00000000  6c 69 6e 65 20 31 0a 20  20 20 73 6f 6d 65 74 68  |line 1.   someth|
00000010  69 6e 67 20 65 6c 73 65  0a                       |ing else.|
00000019
$ a4 Question.g4
$ javac Q*.java
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:4='line ',<'line '>,1:0]
[@1,5:5='1',<NUMBER>,1:5]
[@2,6:9='\n   ',<NEWLINE>,1:6]
[@3,10:23='something else',<'something else'>,2:3]
[@4,24:24='\n',<NEWLINE>,2:17]
[@5,25:24='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
Question last update 2108
found <<line 1
   something else
>>
```

Now change `statement` like so :

```
statement
//  :   'line ' NUMBER NEWLINE 'something else' NEWLINE
    :   'line ' NUMBER         'something else' NEWLINE // now NL will be extraneous
    ;
```

and execute again :

```
$ a4 Question.g4
$ javac Q*.java
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:4='line ',<'line '>,1:0]
[@1,5:5='1',<NUMBER>,1:5]
[@2,6:9='\n   ',<NEWLINE>,1:6]
[@3,10:23='something else',<'something else'>,2:3]
[@4,24:24='\n',<NEWLINE>,2:17]
[@5,25:24='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
Question last update 2114
line 1:6 extraneous input '\n   ' expecting 'something else'
found <<line 1
   something else
>>
```

Note that the NL character and spaces have been correctly matched by the `NEWLINE` lexer rule.

You can find the explanation in section 9.1 of [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) :

> $ grun Simple prog ➾ class T ; { int i; } ➾EOF ❮ line 1:8 extraneous
>   input ';' expecting '{'
>
> A Parade of Errors • 153
>
> The parser reports an error at the ; but gives a slightly more
>   informative answer because it knows that the next token is what it was
>   actually looking for. This feature is called single-token deletion
>   because the parser can simply pretend the extraneous token isn’t there
>   and keep going.
>
> Similarly, the parser can do single-token insertion when it detects a
>   missing token.

In other word, ANTLR4 is so powerful that it can resynchronize the input with the grammar even if several tokens are mismatching. If you run with the -gui option

```
$ grun Question question -gui t.text
```

you can see that ANTLR4 **has parsed the whole file**, despite the fact that a `NEWLINE` is missing in the `statement` rule, and that the input does not match exactly the grammar.

[image]

To summary : `extraneous input` is quite a common error when developing a grammar. It can come from a mismatch between *input to parse* and *rule expectations*, or also because some piece of input has been interpreted by another token than the one we believe, which can be detected by examining the list of tokens produced by the `-tokens` option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While in the end it was not the source of my problems, it has helped me to realize where I was getting stumped and so I will accept it and reward the bounty. For completeness sake, the problem in my case was that the Python input file had a # Comment with another *indented* # Comment below it and the grammar could not handle that. Thanks again for your time and for an informative answer.